# Best way to access and store data independant of the object in a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I have a class with some properties that are object dependant and some properties that doesn't change, whatever the object that has been instanciate from this class.

I want to create a method `list_avail_sc` that is callable from the object and that prints the class property `_list_avail_sc` (which is independant from the object). How can I store the the list of strings and print them cleanly?

```
class SpacecraftSimulator:

    _list_avail_sc = ['Soyuz_HP', 'Dragon_2', 'Dragon_open_4']

    def __init__(self, sc_name='Soyuz_HP_10'):
        self.sc_name = sc_name

    def list_avail_sc():
        """Print to the user the list of available 3D models for simulation"""
        print("Following Spacecrafts are available for simulation:")
        print('\n'.join(_list_avail_sc))

    @property
    def sc_name(self):
        return self._sc_name

    @property.setter
    def sc_name(self, sc_name):
        """Set the 3D model used. If this model is not supported,
        raise an exception"""
        if sc_name in _list_avail_sc:
            self._sc_name = sc_name
            print("Using spacecraft model {}".format(sc_name))
        else:
            self.list_avail_sc()
            raise Exception('Requested spacecraft unavailable')
```

Thank you

Comment: I assume this is what you're looking for: https://pythonbasics.org/classmethod/

Comment: @olinox: it looks like it. Thanks!

Comment: You can just use `self._list_avail_sc`... instances have access to the class state, indeed, how else do you thing `self.some_method()` works? Methosd are attributes of the class. As an aside, **don't use list-comprehensions for side effects**: `[ print(sc) for sc in _list_avail_sc ]`

Comment: @Maltergate you *don't* need a classmethod, especially if your intention is to call it on an instance.

Comment: Oh right... Thing is, it _feels_ not right to do it with some `self._list_avail_sc` because it's not object dependant. Like, whatever the object is, do, becomes, the list is always the same and shall not change.